# F# alternative List Syntax

Tags: f#

so i have got a type Genre with Property Name on it.

Im creating a list of Genre Names like below.

```
let genres = new Genre()
    [ genres.Name <- "Disco"; 
      genres.Name <- "Jazz"; 
      genres.Name <- "Rock"; ] |>ignore
```

Wondering if there is more succint way of creating this ?.

Comment: Note that your code probably doesn't do what you think - you are creating a single Genre and setting its name three different times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
["Disco"; "Jazz"; "Rock"]
|> List.map (fun name -> Genre(name))
```

Comment: I quite like John's idea , but bit torn between which one to choose. Anyhow maybe chose yours. Thanks Daniel.

Comment: My take: `["Disco"; "Jazz"; "Rock"] |> List.map Genre`

Comment: @pblasucci: I wish that works, but constructors can't be used as first-class functions. You could, however, use a static factory method, but I'm not sure it would save many keystrokes.

Comment: @Daniel: Ah, good point. I had missed that it was a constructor.

Answer (score 8):

The code in your example creates just a single `Genre` object and then creates a list of `unit` values. A `unit` value is a bit like `void` in C# - it is the result of perfroming an expression that does not return anything, but has a side-effect. In your case, the side-effect is modifying the `Name` property of the single instance (that's what the `<-` operator does), so you end with a single `genres` value whose `Name` is `"Rock"`.

There are numerous ways to change the code to do what you want - to start with what you wrote:

```
let genre = new Genre() 
genre.Name <- "Disco"
```

This creates a single `genre` value, so you could create values `genre1`, `genre2` and `genre3` and then turn them into a list using:

```
let genres = [ genre1; genre2; genre3 ]
```

That would be quite a lot of repetition. If you have a default constructor for `Genre` that takes the name, you can just write `Genre("Disco")`. If you don't, you can use F# object initialization syntax and specify the value of the property during the construction as `Genre(Name="Disco")`. Note you can also omit `new` if the object does not implement `IDisposable`.

Now you can construct a list like this:

```
let genres = [ Genre(Name="Disco"); Genre(Name="Jazz"); Genre(Name="Rock") ]
```

Now, you can start using functional features like `List.map` (as suggested by Daniel) or F# list comprehension syntax to make the construction even shorter. In this case, I would probably prefer list comprehension and I'd write:

```
let genres = [ for name in ["Disco"; "Jazz"; "Rock"] -> Genre(Name = name) ]
```

This does the same thing as `List.map`, but using an F# syntax that has been designed for this purpose.

**EDIT:** Aside, using mutable properties in F# is not always the best way to go. You could try solving the same problem using F# records, which give you an easy way to create copies with modified properties. For example:

```
// A genre has a name and an era
type Genre = { Name : string; Era : string; }

// Create a template with the basic properties set
let template = { Name = "Default"; Era = "Twentieth century" }

// Create a list of 20th century genres
let genres = [ { template with Name = "Disco" }
               { template with Name = "Jazz" }
               { template with Name = "Rock" } ]
```

Unlike in the previous case, records are immutable and so you don't risk the confusion that is caused when you create a mutable object and then mutate it. Here, you get a list of three different objects (that are created by copying the `template`).

Comment: How does "designed for this purpose" apply more to list comprehension syntax than `List.map`?

Comment: @Tomas, thanks for the explanation, I wasn't aware of F# object initialization syntax. Was infact wondering there must be similar way as we do in C#. Nice.

Comment: @Daniel "designed for this purpose" applies to both, but "syntax designed for this purpose" applies only to comprehension syntax. I'm not implying that comprehension syntax is better, just because it exists, but I think it looks nicer in this case (if you could use constructor as first-class function, I would prefer `List.map` too).

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way would be to use a construcotr which did the assignment for you, then you could write

```
let genres = Genre("Disco")::Genre("Jazz")::Genre("Rock")::[]
```

Comment: I would argue that `[ Genre("Disco"); Genre("Jazz"); Genre("Rock") ]` is better syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more terser:

```
type Genre = Genre of string
let genres = List.map Genre ["Disco"; "Jazz"; "Rock"]

printfn "%A" genres
```

Prints `[Genre "Disco"; Genre "Jazz"; Genre "Rock"]`.

Comment: He wants to create `Genre` objects. Your solution makes `Genre` discriminated unions.

Comment: @pad, a discriminated union with one case would technically be isomorphic to a record definition.

Comment: @pad, I understand the OP is probably using `class`, but I am just providing an alternative.